# sn.exe can't find my registered managed dll

Tags: .net, com, typelib

I have registered COM DLL made according this tutorial - http://cppkid.wordpress.com/2009/01/02/how-to-call-a-managed-dll-from-unmanaged-code/. I created snk file, copied it in the solution folder(solution file is in source folder) and after building the dll I registered it successfully with the regasm command(tried with and without /console option). But to use use it in the app I need the PublicKeyToken, but when I call

> ```
> sn -T MyDLL.dll
> ```

or

> ```
> sn -T MyDLL.tlb
> ```

, the result is:

> ```
> Failed to read MyDLL.dll -- The system cannot find the file specified.
> ```

I even tried to output the dll and tlb files where my snk file is, but the result is the same.
I'm using Windows 7 x64 and .NET 4.0.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Approach number one is to use the Regasm.exe /codebase option so this isn't necessary at all.  Approach number two is to use the IDE so it is all automatically done without getting killed by subtle little mistakes like having the default directory wrong.  Project + Properties, Signing tab.  Press F1 if you need more help.

Comment: With "/console option)" i meant/codebase. I don't know why I wrote "console". like @vcsjones said i forgot the fullpath, but now the result of sn command is:
` MyDLL.tlb does not represent a strongly named assembly`
I'm trying to set domain manager type with
`clrControl->SetAppDomainManagerType(L("mydll, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=???, processorArchitecture=MSIL"), L("mydll.AppDomainManager") )`
but it I can't find the PublicKeyToken. This way
`clrControl->SetAppDomainManagerType(L("mydll"),L("mydll.AppDomainManager") )`
 it works :)
Thank you both of you for the help.

Comment: You cannot strong-name a type library, only an assembly.  A DLL, not a TLB.  You don't want to use Regasm to register this DLL in this case, ICLRControl::SetAppDomainManagerType() doesn't require it.  Beware DLL Hell with the shortcut you found.  You did get this all mixed up a bit :)

Answer (score 0):

`sn` expects to be able to find `MyDLL.dll` in the path. It doesn't matter if it is COM or not, or if it's registered. You probably mean to do something like this:

```
sn -Tp C:\full\path\to\your\assembly\MyDLL.dll
```